# how to remove outermost logic?

Tags: excel, logic

how to remove outermost logic?

such as

```
input column D result
And(OR(A,B),C) 

output column E binary number
OR(A,B)

A   B   C   result(D)after extract(E)
0   0   0   0        0
0   0   1   0        0 
0   1   0   0        1
0   1   1   1        1
1   0   0   0        1
1   0   1   1        1
1   1   0   0        1
1   1   1   1        1
```

i tried in excel

```
=IF(NOT(AND(D2,C2))=TRUE,1,0)
```

but can not remove outermost logic

```
            result  after extract   
0   0   0   =IF(AND(OR(A2,B2),C2)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(OR(A2,B2)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(NOT(AND(D2,C2))=TRUE,1,0)
0   0   1   =IF(AND(OR(A3,B3),C3)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(OR(A3,B3)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(NOT(AND(D3,C3))=TRUE,1,0)
0   1   0   =IF(AND(OR(A4,B4),C4)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(OR(A4,B4)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(NOT(AND(D4,C4))=TRUE,1,0)
0   1   1   =IF(AND(OR(A5,B5),C5)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(OR(A5,B5)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(NOT(AND(D5,C5))=TRUE,1,0)
1   0   0   =IF(AND(OR(A6,B6),C6)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(OR(A6,B6)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(NOT(AND(D6,C6))=TRUE,1,0)
1   0   1   =IF(AND(OR(A7,B7),C7)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(OR(A7,B7)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(NOT(AND(D7,C7))=TRUE,1,0)
1   1   0   =IF(AND(OR(A8,B8),C8)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(OR(A8,B8)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(NOT(AND(D8,C8))=TRUE,1,0)
1   1   1   =IF(AND(OR(A9,B9),C9)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(OR(A9,B9)=TRUE,1,0) =IF(NOT(AND(D9,C9))=TRUE,1,0)
```

Comment: i know because different area have different expert

Comment: mathoverflow is downvoting my question, i am afraid i ask in wrong place

Comment: This seems programming related.  I think SO is the right place for this question.

Comment: i search many times in google and trial and error many times in excel, still find no solutions for this, never read a book mentioning about this, is there any one know how to extract this.

Answer (score 0):

By "remove the outermost logic", I assume you want to remove the `IF` function.

One thing to note is that in a formula like `=IF(AND(OR(A2,B2),C2)=TRUE,1,0)` you never need the `=TRUE` test. `=IF(AND(OR(A2,B2),C2),1,0)` will work exactly the same.

There are a couple of ways to convert a boolean (i.e. true/false value) into an integer without the explicit `IF`. One is `--AND(OR(A2,B2),C2)`. Another is `int(AND(OR(A2,B2),C2))`.